# STS hanging after JUnit test

Tags: eclipse, junit, spring-tool-suite

I'm running a junit test (junit version 4.8.1) but when I after the test has run STS hangs for about 5 minutes no matter on the outcome of the test.

Is there any configuration that could possibly have this effect?? I have multiple projects on my STS and the other project tests work as normal with no hang.

Please Help!!

Comment: Is there any chance to provide a few steps how to reproduce this? Or create an issue at https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS with a sample project attached?

Comment: When something is hanging it is always a good idea to use 'jps' and 'jstack' commands to collect a stackdump. It might help diagnose what's causing the hang.

Comment: I have found this issue to be a problem with STS. After running the test, and it fails, STS will search through the console to find the error to display. This then uses pattern matching which, if the console is massive, will cause the hanging. Anyone have any ideas on fixing this issue/development is ongoing for this? I currently have the console switched off and outputting to a file